# I get this error on react native MacOS big sur "use_native_modules! skipped the react-native dependency 'react-native-os'. No podspec file was found."

Tags: xcode, react-native, visual-studio-code, yarn-workspaces

use_native_modules! skipped the react-native dependency 'react-native-os'. No podspec file was found.
- Check to see if there is an updated version that contains the necessary podspec file
- Contact the library maintainers or send them a PR to add a podspec. The react-native-webview podspec is a good example of a package.json driven podspec. See
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/react-native-webview.podspec
- If necessary, you can disable autolinking for the dependency and link it manually. See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md#how-can-i-disable-autolinking-for-unsupported-library

first I generated the ios folder and android folder.

yarn add react-native-eject

npx react-native eject

then I typed pod install and after that I get that error.